# 'inserted' event not fired for Component (CanJS, JSFiddle)

Tags: event-handling, canjs, canjs-component

For some reason the [`inserted` event](https://v2.canjs.com/docs/can.events.inserted.html) is not fired for any component in my set-up in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bair_web/s7dgvvac/).

I'm trying to play with view bindings here, but the basic (hard coded) data aren't produced and used at all. No `console.log` line of a callback of an `inserted`-event appears, therefore I think, that this event isn't fired. But the `keyup`-event on the input element is interestingly fired.

Am I missing any can library (from a CDN) here? Any other idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`can.stache` returns a renderer function, so you need to call it in order to correctly create a document fragment.

I think changing this:

`$('#can-bindings').append(can.stache('<search-comp />'));`

to:

`$('#can-bindings').append(can.stache('<search-comp />')());`

in each of the places where you're trying to render templates should solve your problem.

Comment: Oh year, the **renderer function**. I'm still forgetting this. Thanks!